# DockerHub + GitHub with a team

Tags: github, dockerhub

I'm not sure I understand the point of DockerHub. I understand GitHub as a code repository, but DockerHub kinda throws me through a loop. When I share code with a team we use GitHub, but DockerHub would be for the images and volumes? So a new team member pulls that down from DockerHub, and then once that's up and running with `docker-compose up`, then they run `git pull origin master` so the code will be updated?

Please help me understand this. :)

Answer (score 1):

*[From Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/): Docker Hub is a cloud-based registry service which allows you to link to code repositories, build your images and test them, stores manually pushed images, and links to Docker Cloud so you can deploy images to your hosts. It provides a centralized resource for container image discovery, distribution and change management, user and team collaboration, and workflow automation throughout the development pipeline.*

GitHub hosts the code, and the code is managed via `git`, which is the best way to handle the source code changes. DockerHub provides the bits that GitHub isn't meant for: registering your dockerfiles, building the images, etc.

DockerHub organizations & team functionality give your team access to these shared image repositories.

Organizations on GitHub and DockerHub function in a similar manner, but are complementary services because they handle totally different jobs.

Comment: Also, Dockerhub stores precompiled versions of dockerfiles (the iamges themselves) so they can be "pulled" instead of compiled in your computer when you build a dockerfile for the first time. It is a huge time saver!

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! How do I share volumes then? Wouldn't that be on DockerHub? So a new member would pull down from DockerHub and compose up, then they'd have the images and volumes? And then pull from the GitHub repo for the updated code?

Comment: Edited answer; in short DockerHub is where you share the images; I don't believe DockerHub hosts volumes.

Comment: I have a wordpress container that has a wp-content volume for creating a child theme and a mysql container that has a volume to persist content changes (posts). Is there not a way to persist this data (posts & pages in the db) and share this with other devs on the team, or when being pushed to staging and then prod? Sorry for so many questions. You've been very helpful so far. :)

Comment: There probably is, you should ask a second question for it tho, comments not the best place.